# Using CodeIgniter to Check if Field Value is Unique

Tags: php, arrays, database, codeigniter, unique

I'm trying to check if a value being added to the database is `unique.`

This is the code I'm using, but the `in_array()` never returns `true`, even when I know the number is already in the database.  Am I misunderstanding `result_array()` or `something?`

```
//Check if Serial is Already in Database 
$this->db->select('fldUserSensorID');
$sensorqry = $this->db->get("tblMonitoringSensors");
$result = $sensorqry->result_array();

if (in_array($this->input->post('serialNumber'), $result)) {
    $attempt=false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `result_array()` which should have data like this `Array`:-

```
Array(
  0=>Array("fldUserSensorID"=>1),
  1=>Array("fldUserSensorID"=>3),
  2=>Array("fldUserSensorID"=>9)
)
```

so you should try this:

```
$optimized_result=array_column($result, 'fldUserSensorID');
if (in_array($this->input->post('serialNumber'), $optimized_result)) {
                $attempt=false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand what you're trying to do is validate a value against your database values and see if the value you're trying to insert is already there or not.

For that you don't need any new function or even make the query to the database yourself.

You should use the form validation to take care of that. There's a validation rule just for this purpose.

Here's how to do it:

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('fldUserSensorID', 'fldUserSensorID', 'required|is_unique[tblMonitoringSensors.fldUserSensorID]');

if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {
    // Error here
} else {
   // Success
}
```

In these rules I'm saying that fldUserSensorID must be required and must be unique in the tblMonitoringSensors table.